# Headers not sending correctly with python 2.6.6 and httplib

Tags: python, httplib

I have a very basic python script that I am using to hit a specific endpoint. For some reason I cannot get it to send the authorization header I need it to send on a specific server. The information below is fictitious but is a good example of what i am doing. I wrote this script which runs fine on my virtual machine but not on the actual server. Python version are both 2.6.6. I can't change the version, so please don't suggest updating. I am writing this question to get guidance as the why the header might be getting removed.

The environments are literally identical and use a configuration manager to maintain the consistency of their settings.

Here is the script. Pretty straight forward. I'm just making an API call to return a user model based on the access token.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import httplib, os, socket

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(socket.gethostname())
conn.set_debuglevel(1)
conn.putrequest("GET", "/api/index.php/user")
conn.putheader('Authorization','Bearer 123456')
conn.endheaders()
response = conn.getresponse()

print response.status
print response.reason
print response.read()
```

**Request & debug info on my VM**

```
[root@vm scripts]# ./test.py 
send: 'GET /api/index.php/user 
    HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Host: vm.shibby.com\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n
    Authorization: Bearer 123456\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 22:18:00 GMT
header: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
header: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN
header: Connection: close
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
200
OK
```

**Request as received by VM - dumped to logs**

```
2014-03-10 22:18:00 --- DEBUG: headers: HTTP_Header Object
(
    [_accept_content:protected] => 
    [_accept_charset:protected] => 
    [_accept_encoding:protected] => 
    [_accept_language:protected] => 
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
    (
        [authorization] => Bearer 123456
        [host] => vm.shibby.com
        [accept-encoding] => identity
        [connection] => close
    )
)
```

**Output on my server**

```
[root@vm scripts]# ./test.py
send: 'GET /api/index.php/user 
    HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Host: shibby.com\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n
    Authorization: Bearer 123456\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
header: Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 22:24:55 GMT
header: Server: Apache
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: Content-Length: 37
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Type: application/json
400
Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_token"}
```

**Request as received by the server**

```
2014-03-10 22:33:23 --- DEBUG: headers: HTTP_Header Object
(
    [_accept_content:protected] => 
    [_accept_charset:protected] => 
    [_accept_encoding:protected] => 
    [_accept_language:protected] => 
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [host] => shibby.com
            [accept-encoding] => identity
            [connection] => close
        )

)
```

As you can see, the authorization header is not received by the endpoint in question. There is NO processing that happens at this point, I am logging in the constructor of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i left some important information out. The framework I am using is Kohana 3.2 and apparently it strips the authorization header out. I had gotten around this by adding a line to set it as an environment variable in apache. Looks like that was not being run because i was not accessing the end point as the subdomain that it is, https://api.shibby.com. Anyway, hope this helps someone else.